# which is the example of type selector

Tags: jquery

I have a question regarding jQuery.

What is an example of type selector?

1) h1

2) .h1

3) #h1

4) div h1

5) div>h1

Can anybody tell me what would be the correct answer?

Thanks

Comment: @Sukhi: All selectors mentioned above can be a type selector in jQuery. For more details see my answer below.

Comment: Is this homework? (1) is a type selector. (4) and (5) use type selectors. (2) and (3) are not.

Comment: @nnnnnn: actually my friend asked me this question and i don't know correct answer.so i think according to you correct answer is 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**type selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#type-selectors) matches the name of a document language element type. A type selector matches every instance of the element type in the document tree.

**h1**

Example: `$("h1")`

The above rule selects all `h1` elements in the document tree

**.h1**

Example: `$(".h1")`

The above rule selects all elements having attribute `class="h1"` in the document tree

**#h1**

Example: `$("#h1")`

The above rule selects all elements having attribute `id="h1"` in the document tree

**div h1**

Example: `$("div h1")`

The above rule selects all `div` elements having `h1` elements in the document tree

**div > h1**

Example: `$("div > h1")`

The above rule selects all `h1` elements that are children of `div` element in the document tree

Comment: In the context of an html document, doesn't "name of a document language element type" effectively mean "tag names"? `<h1>` is an html element, and the selector `"h1"` will select it. `"#h1"` doesn't match a particular element type, it matches on id attribute of _any_ element type. The w3 document you linked to puts id selectors under their own heading, and class selectors are listed as a subheading under attribute selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Googling your question at all??

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#type-selectors